# Cannot install distribute: pypi.python.org rejecting http

Tags: python, pypi, distribute

This worked yesterday (I am fairly sure) and started failing only today. Any ideas/workaround on what I can do to install this package?

Doing curl to fetch this URL clearly shows the server is just rejecting with " 403 SSL is required" and not even redirecting to the https:// url.

```
# pip install hotqueue
Collecting hotqueue
  Using cached hotqueue-0.2.7.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/d/distribute/distribute-0.6.14.tar.gz
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-wZ7k8g/hotqueue/setup.py", line 7, in <module>
        from distribute_setup import use_setuptools; use_setuptools()
      File "/tmp/pip-build-wZ7k8g/hotqueue/distribute_setup.py", line 145, in use_setuptools
        return _do_download(version, download_base, to_dir, download_delay)
      File "/tmp/pip-build-wZ7k8g/hotqueue/distribute_setup.py", line 124, in _do_download
        to_dir, download_delay)
      File "/tmp/pip-build-wZ7k8g/hotqueue/distribute_setup.py", line 193, in download_setuptools
        src = urlopen(url)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
        return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 435, in open
        response = meth(req, response)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 548, in http_response
        'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 473, in error
        return self._call_chain(*args)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 407, in _call_chain
        result = func(*args)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 556, in http_error_default
        raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
    urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: SSL is required

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-wZ7k8g/hotqueue/
```

Comment: The library seems to have its own and outdated dependencies installation routine which tries to do HTTP to an HTTPS only server.

Comment: As to why this only started failing today: https://mail.python.org/pipermail/distutils-sig/2017-October/031712.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is answered here: [Getting error 403 while installing package with pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46967488/getting-error-403-while-installing-package-with-pip)

Here is the link they provided: https://mail.python.org/pipermail/distutils-sig/2017-October/031712.html

Short answer: http support dropped from pypi on Oct 26, 2017.

Comment: Checked that answer. I still get the same error message. Any other suggestions?