# Getting error 403 while installing package with pip

Tags: python, google-app-engine, pip

getting an error while installing google app engine using pip

```
Collecting google_appengine
  Downloading google-appengine-1.5.1.tar.gz (897kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 901kB 1.9MB/s 
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/d/distribute/distribute-0.6.14.tar.gz
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/88/5jq5gz011sl63h_37k_qftv40000gn/T/pip-build-vxx8Ov/google-appengine/setup.py", line 3, in <module>
        ez_setup.use_setuptools()
      File "/Users/user/path to project/project/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ez_setup.py", line 145, in use_setuptools
        return _do_download(version, download_base, to_dir, download_delay)
      File "/Users/user/path to project/project/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ez_setup.py", line 124, in _do_download
        to_dir, download_delay)
      File "/Users/user/path to project/project/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ez_setup.py", line 193, in download_setuptools
        src = urlopen(url)
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
        return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 437, in open
        response = meth(req, response)
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 550, in http_response
        'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 475, in error
        return self._call_chain(*args)
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 409, in _call_chain
        result = func(*args)
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 558, in http_error_default
        raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
    urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: SSL is required

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/88/5jq5gz011sl63h_37k_qftv40000gn/T/pip-build-vxx8Ov/google-appengine/`
```

Comment: can you try it with **--trusted-host** parameter 

`pip install --index-url=http://pypi.python.org/simple/ --trusted-host pypi.python.org google-appengine `

Comment: No Its not working

Comment: can you provide OS details ? and try updated command

Comment: I am using OSX and tried above command  got this error
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement google-appengine (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for google-appengine

Comment: It looks like issue with pip itself https://github.com/pyca/cryptography/issues/2692
try upgrading pip if it works 
`pip install --upgrade pip` or you can try with `easy_install2.7 google-appengine`

Comment: Pip is the latest version

Comment: even with `easy_install google-appengine` isn't working?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157629/discussion-between-keshaw-pathak-and-mahesh-karia).

Comment: below solution is not working for me! Any other solution, I'm facing the same issue while installing google-appengine

Comment: which package are you trying to install ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It's because PyPI has disabled non HTTPS access to APIs

https://mail.python.org/pipermail/distutils-sig/2017-October/031712.html

as workaround you can use

```
$ pip install xxxx -i https://pypi.python.org/simple/
```

Comment: Now thousands github python repos all over the place will start getting 403 SSL issues from users. A round of applause to distutils team.

Comment: If you know the URL of the project you can install directly from there. For example, `pip install git+https://github.com/<user>/<project>`.

Comment: @MaxShenfield, thanks, being able to use git with pip is SOOO useful!

Comment: this did not work unless we upgraded the libssl on our 12.04 ubuntu!

Comment: Does not work for me

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately none of the previous answers work for me.

IMHO it was very stupid pip / distutils chose to break packages on http repos.

I think a better choice would have been:

- pip/distutils use https by default
- in case of error, like 403, pip has to suggest you "the package repo is on http, do you want to download it?"

Still in 2020 many Python 2 packages are on http repos; with their decision, the installation of these packages is broken.

---

The working solution for me is a very simple patch of one python core modules:

```
--- /usr/local/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py.original
+++ /usr/local/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py
@@ -427,6 +427,9 @@
             req = meth(req)

         response = self._open(req, data)
+        if protocol == "http" and response.code == 403 :
+            if isinstance(fullurl, basestring) and fullurl.startswith("http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/d/distribute/") :
+                return    self.open(fullurl.replace("http://", "https://"), data = data, timeout = timeout)

         # post-process response
         meth_name = protocol+"_response"
```

Working: if the failed url is on http, retry on https.

I know it is a little ugly, but it is very clear and also you can revert to the original module in a snap (make a copy of */usr/local/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py* before to apply this patch).

Comment: Thanks a lot! This fix of yours is really MUCH more useful (and elegant) than the accepted answer, especially because that one doesn't seem to work anymore either.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that worked for me was using easy_install instead of pip

Answer (score 0):

If the Python project has a Git URL then you can try this command which will do pip install with git.

```
python -m pip install git+https://github.com/<user>/<project>
```

However, if the project has any dependencies and the dependencies also suffer from same problem (the usual case), then such dependencies will also fail.

Answer (score -1):

Got the error.
The problem was with the repo from where pip was trying to install the package.

Comment: How did you fix this problem?