# Error popping up while installing 'spc' module in python 2.7 . Can't find the solution

Tags: python-2.7, spc

I'm trying to install spc module on python.

I get an error which says "urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: SSL is required". How do I proceed? I have tried a lot of things that are given,still doesn't seem to woek

urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: SSL is required

n [1]: import spc

In [2]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

In [3]: x = [25,19,14,17,25,39,49,6,11,19,13,26,24,32,14,19]

In [4]: cc = spc.Spc(x, spc.CHART_X_MR_X)

In [5]: cc.get_chart()

In [6]: plt.show()

This is the code i am using!

Comment: Can you show the command how you're installing the module?

Comment: Could someone Please be of any help! 

I also tried downloading the package package and pasting it in the 'site packages' folder. Still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Since I cannot comment, i'm writing in answer section.

This link is helpful 
https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/

This SO answer can be of some help. 
[Getting error 403 while installing package with pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46967488/getting-error-403-while-installing-package-with-pip)

try upgrading `pip`.