# Pip install fails: SSL required

Tags: python, dependencies, pip, rsa

```
Collecting rsa==3.1.1 (from -r /racetrack/.requirements.txt (line 41))
eval (python -m virtualfish)
  Downloading rsa-3.1.1.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/d/distribute/distribute-0.6.10.tar.gz
    Traceback (most recent call last):          
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 558, in http_error_default
        raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
    urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: SSL is required
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Solution: Upgrade to the latest version of your library.**

It all starts here, suddenly(on Oct-2017) the Distutils team decided to revoke support for non-https requests without worrying about breaking the backward compatibility of earlier versions of numerous python libraries. Bit unprofessional, but hey it's Python world.

So here is the fix, Simply move on to the latest version of the library (`rsa==3.4.2` in my case) on whatever library (`nltk==3.2.5` etc)

**Alternate Solution: Fork(or locally copy) the version of repo & modify the `http` url into `https`**

Nonetheless, watch out if you are doing this while maintaining another project since the dependency you are upgrading might not be compatible with the original library the author had intended, for example in my context `rsa` was used under another library as a dependency. Thus the solution was to upgrade the parent library so that this issue is automatically taken care.

Comment: Distutils release note(Oct-2017): https://mail.python.org/pipermail/distutils-sig/2017-October/031714.html

Comment: I found this answer to be unhelpful.  Which library?  How to do this?

Comment: @SoloPilot The point of this answer is that multiple libraries potentially have the problem described in the question. You should upgrade to the latest version *of the library that you are trying to install*. This pre-supposes that the library maintainers updated their setup scripts in the new version. Many older libraries have just dropped support entirely. Modern guides for packaging new projects don't even expect you to use `distutils` any more.

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately none of the previous answers work for me.

IMHO it was very stupid pip / distutils chose to break packages on http repos.

I think a better choice would have been:

- pip/distutils use https by default
- in case of error, like 403, pip has to suggest you "the package repo is on http, do you want to download it?"

Still in 2020 many Python 2 packages are on http repos; with their decision, the installation of these packages is broken.

---

The working solution for me is a very simple patch of one python core modules:

```
--- /usr/local/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py.original
+++ /usr/local/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py
@@ -427,6 +427,9 @@
             req = meth(req)

         response = self._open(req, data)
+        if protocol == "http" and response.code == 403 :
+            if isinstance(fullurl, basestring) and fullurl.startswith("http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/d/distribute/") :
+                return    self.open(fullurl.replace("http://", "https://"), data = data, timeout = timeout)

         # post-process response
         meth_name = protocol+"_response"
```

Working: if the failed url is on http, retry on https.

I know it is a little ugly, but it is very clear and also you can revert to the original module in a snap (make a copy of */usr/local/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py* before to apply this patch).

Comment: This solution is NOT ugly, at least to the level of their decision to drop support.

Comment: Thank you. This is the only solution that worked for me, too.

Comment: Works like a charm. If you're using an existing a virtualenv, you may need to recreate it after applying this change.

Comment: "Still in 2020 many Python 2 packages are on http repos" Since 2020 it is **your fault** if you have problems installing a Python 2 package because Python 2 *itself* is [not supported as of Jan 1, 2020](https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/). Python 2.7 is as outdated as Windows 7.

Answer (score 2):

Just an `easy_install rsa==3.1.1` will do the job.

Comment: HTTPError 403: 'SSL is required'

Comment: Which OS are you using ?

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer did not work in my case (on an elder Raspbian), but providing the download URL with the command helped me as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46979531/1037303) post:

```
sudo pip install paho-mqtt -i https://pypi.python.org/simple
```

Comment: You can also use `sudo pip install -U pip -i https://pypi.python.org/simple` to definitely fix the problem!

Answer (score 0):

Using easy_install rather than pip worked for me:

```
easy_install funkload
```

I was attempting to `pip install funkload` and was getting:

```
Collecting funkload
  Using cached funkload-1.17.1.tar.gz
  Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
  Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/d/distribute/distribute-0.6.14.tar.gz
  Traceback (most recent call last):
...<snip>
  urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: SSL is required
```

As funkload dates from 2011, the older easy_install works.