# Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-8ryfpf0v/unroll/

Tags: python, pip

can someone help me, i don't know what to do to solve this problem

```
student@jethost:~$  pip install unroll
```

`Collecting unroll
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fe/3c/124bdf4276e582c8e4e23ce27c4462a259f6608df8e550d30f003f2b4189/unroll-0.1.0.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/d/distribute/distribute-0.6.14.tar.gz
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/student/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ez_setup.py", line 143, in use_setuptools
        raise ImportError
    ImportError`

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-install-8ryfpf0v/unroll/setup.py", line 2, in <module>
    ez_setup.use_setuptools()
  File "/home/student/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ez_setup.py", line 145, in use_setuptools
    return _do_download(version, download_base, to_dir, download_delay)
  File "/home/student/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ez_setup.py", line 124, in _do_download
    to_dir, download_delay)
  File "/home/student/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ez_setup.py", line 193, in download_setuptools
    src = urlopen(url)
  File "/home/student/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 223, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/home/student/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 532, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/home/student/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 642, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/home/student/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 570, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/home/student/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/home/student/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 650, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: SSL is required

----------------------------------------
```

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-8ryfpf0v/unroll/

Comment: What does `pip --version` say? Try use search: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46967488/getting-error-403-while-installing-package-with-pip/46979531#46979531

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://pypi.org/project/unroll/#history — last release was in 2014. `ez_setup.use_setuptools` also was deprecated from `setuptools` many years ago (it was so long ago I don't remember when). A [bug report](https://github.com/Zulko/Unroll/issues) was opened in 2017 — still hasn't got any replies from the author. The code seems too old and abandoned, and I'm sure it doesn't work with Python 3.

Comment: It notably only ever got 8 commits. Seems quite dead.