# getting a 403 error when fetching a zip file in pip

Tags: python, apache, pip, http-status-code-403

I am installing python packages with pip using urls in the `requirements.txt` file:

```
https://devdownloads.protopixel.net/python_dependencies/pyOSC-0.3.5b-5294.zip
```

Running `pip install -r requirements` results in a 403 error:

```
(testenv) protopixel@ppxnode-421E2FF:~/proto_light_simulator/snap$ pip install -r requirements.txt
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7.
Collecting https://devdownloads.protopixel.net/python_dependencies/pyOSC-0.3.5b-5294.zip (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
  ERROR: HTTP error 403 while getting https://devdownloads.protopixel.net/python_dependencies/pyOSC-0.3.5b-5294.zip
  ERROR: Could not install requirement https://devdownloads.protopixel.net/python_dependencies/pyOSC-0.3.5b-5294.zip (from -r requirements.txt (line 1)) because of error 403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: https://devdownloads.protopixel.net/python_dependencies/pyOSC-0.3.5b-5294.zip
ERROR: Could not install requirement https://devdownloads.protopixel.net/python_dependencies/pyOSC-0.3.5b-5294.zip (from -r requirements.txt (line 1)) because of HTTP error 403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: https://devdownloads.protopixel.net/python_dependencies/pyOSC-0.3.5b-5294.zip for URL https://devdownloads.protopixel.net/python_dependencies/pyOSC-0.3.5b-5294.zip
```

However a simple wget will work ok.

I am confused on whether this is a problem on the pip side, a OS-related issue or a server configuration issue (Apache). Any insights on how can I debug that?

Comment: I can confirm the problem. `curl` and `wget` download the file just fine but `pip` doesn't. It seems the site specifically prevents `pip` to download the file or may be it rejects any unknown download agent. Only the site's admin could say. Can you try other Python package managers like `pipenv`?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46967488/getting-error-403-while-installing-package-with-pip

Answer (score 0):

Just let pip do the job. Tested, in a Ubuntu Xenial container:

```
root@9f411ba3b846:/# pip install pyOSC
Collecting pyOSC
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7c/e4/6abb118cf110813a7922119ed0d53e5fe51c570296785ec2a39f37606d85/pyOSC-0.3.5b-5294.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: pyOSC
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pyOSC ... done
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/df/6a/66/769db4893bd6f5b52d1640661f2fcdee9c49b62e4b934b4686
Successfully built pyOSC
Installing collected packages: pyOSC
Successfully installed pyOSC-0.3.5b5294
```