# Unable to Install MySqlclient packages using pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, mysql-python, mysql-connector

My System is Windows10 and has Installed with **Python 3.7.1** and  **Anaconda3** in it.

pip version is: **18.1**

Now I am trying to Install the Python MySQL Client Packages using the pip following command and getting the below Errors.

1. `pip install mysqlclient`

```
Collecting mysqlclient
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by  'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x00000233D3E948D0>, 
'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/mysqlclient/
```

[image: pip install Error Message]

Since I am using this in my proxy Enabled machine I tried below command

2. `pip install --proxy=http://<servername>:8080/wpad.dat mysqlclient`

which gives me an error asking to have Python >=3.5. Where I Already have 3.7.1 Installed.

[image]

Can anyone please help me what is the Issue.

Comment: you could try `pip install --user mysqlclient`? It looks like you have more than one python installed, so to see which python versions you have installed, try `which -a python` or `which -a python3`.

Comment: @user3479780 - I have only one version Installed which is 3.7.1.  Fire the given command it is throwing an error that which is not a recognized command. python --version returning the version 3.7.1 and also under the programs I can see only one version. Thank you

Comment: PyPI denies non-HTTPS access, so your proxy has to upgrade insecure requests to HTTPS.

Comment: I first closed this as a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/q/46967488/2650249, but then saw there is no actual solution proposed in the linked question, so IMO it's not fair to dupe this.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of console output. They can be hard to read depending on the device used and are not searchable, making it harder for people with similar error messages to find this question. Please use the [edit] button to replace the screenshots with copy/pasted text put into appropriate format.

Answer (score -3):

Pip is deprecated try to use this more convenient command

```
python -m pip install {package}
```

Comment: Pip is definitely not deprecated. But this is a more reliable way to make sure pip is targeting the version of python you want it to. eg. `python38 -m pip ...` or `C:\path\to\python -m pip ...`