# How do I resolve 403 errors with pip install

Tags: python, pip

Im tryig to install a python module that has a dependency, cffi. When I run pip install with trusted hosts I will ocassionally get a 403 error. When I run the same command again it will pass. I have to repeat the same command several times befor it installs.

```
pip install mypythonlib --extra-index-url http://artifactoryhost/artifactory/api/pypi/orginisation/simple --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org --trusted-host corporatehost --no-cache-dir
```

ERROR: HTTP error 403 while getting https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0a/fe/f5090f4b636cef41680510fba13eee107420e6e016a8d30c386eb832a964/cffi-1.15.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl#sha256=f6f824dc3bce0edab5f427efcfb1d63ee75b6fcb7282900ccaf925be84efb0fc (from https://pypi.org/simple/cffi/)
ERROR: Could not install requirement cffi>=1.12 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0a/fe/f5090f4b636cef41680510fba13eee107420e6e016a8d30c386eb832a964/cffi-1.15.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl#sha256=f6f824dc3bce0edab5f427efcfb1d63ee75b6fcb7282900ccaf925be84efb0fc (from cryptography>=1.3->requests-kerberos==0.12.0->pyadwutil>=1.1.4->pymip) because of HTTP error 403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0a/fe/f5090f4b636cef41680510fba13eee107420e6e016a8d30c386eb832a964/cffi-1.15.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl for URL https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0a/fe/f5090f4b636cef41680510fba13eee107420e6e016a8d30c386eb832a964/cffi-1.15.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl#sha256=f6f824dc3bce0edab5f427efcfb1d63ee75b6fcb7282900ccaf925be84efb0fc (from https://pypi.org/simple/cffi/)

This will also happen with lxml

It seems to have intermittent problems with files.pythonhosted.org

Thanks

Comment: I think the issue is that your url is `http`. I think PIP only supports `https`

Comment: I tried pip install mypythonlib --extra-index-url https: ..... But I still get the 403, thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting error 403 while installing package with pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46967488/getting-error-403-while-installing-package-with-pip)