Facing a problem with running a Federated Learning code
I am trying to run the code in the following link shaoxiongji/federated-learning using the following steps:
1- Clone the Repository:
git clone https://github.com/shaoxiongji/federated-learning.git

2- Navigate to the Repository Directory:
cd federated-learning

3- Install Dependencies:
pip install -r requirements.txt

4- Run the Code:
python main_fed.py

but I am facing a problem:
Downloading http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\raineen\federated-learning\main_fed.py", line 29, in <module>
    dataset_train = datasets.MNIST('../data/mnist/', train=True, download=True, transform=trans_mnist)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\raineen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\torchvision\datasets\mnist.py", line 46, in __init__
    self.download()
  File "C:\Users\raineen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\torchvision\datasets\mnist.py", line 114, in download
    data = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\raineen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 216, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\raineen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 525, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\raineen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 634, in http_response
    response = self.parent.error(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\raineen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 557, in error
    result = self._call_chain(*args)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\raineen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 496, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\raineen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 749, in http_error_302
    return self.parent.open(new, timeout=req.timeout)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\raineen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 525, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\raineen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 634, in http_response
    response = self.parent.error(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\raineen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 563, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\raineen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 496, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\raineen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 643, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden

Any assistance, please? I would like to get two figures results like training loss.

check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46967488/getting-error-403-while-installing-package-with-pip
also see this (maybe helpful): https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-fix-error-403-while-installing-package-with-python-pip/
also manually u can install the content of requirements.txt that are seem to be;
torch==0.4.1
torchvision==0.2.1

@maxis112, I am not sure how to apply it, dear sir.

follow these steps;
python -m pip install --upgrade pip (Upgrade pip)
pip cache purge (Clear the Cache)
pip install  --index-url https://pypi.org/simple/ (Use a Different Index URL)
pip install  --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org ( Install Specific Packages with --trusted-host)
Reinstall Python if the issue persists
Note: if u are using proxy then maybe configure it or turn it off for now and check

@maxis112 The same problem I am facing. I did all of them.
