# urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: SSL is required , even with pip upgraded and --index option used

Tags: python, pip

I've already read [Cannot install distribute: pypi.python.org rejecting http](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46962577/cannot-install-distribute-pypi-python-org-rejecting-http) and [Getting error 403 while installing package with pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46967488/getting-error-403-while-installing-package-with-pip) but the work around are not workig

while trying to do

`pip install --upgrade pyls  --index-url=https://pypi.python.org/simple` I got :

```
Collecting pyls
  Using cached pyls-0.1.3.zip
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/d/distribute/distribute-0.6.14.tar.gz
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-PHBndM/pyls/setup.py", line 31, in <module>
        main()
      File "/tmp/pip-build-PHBndM/pyls/setup.py", line 11, in main
        distribute_setup.use_setuptools()
      File "setup_utils/distribute_setup.py", line 145, in use_setuptools
        return _do_download(version, download_base, to_dir, download_delay)
      File "setup_utils/distribute_setup.py", line 124, in _do_download
        to_dir, download_delay)
      File "setup_utils/distribute_setup.py", line 193, in download_setuptools
        src = urlopen(url)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
        return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 435, in open
        response = meth(req, response)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 548, in http_response
        'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 473, in error
        return self._call_chain(*args)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 407, in _call_chain
        result = func(*args)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 556, in http_error_default
        raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
    urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: SSL is required
----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-hdpX4y/pyls/
```

my python version is 2.7, and my pip version is

`pip 9.0.2 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)`

to reproduce :

spin this docker instance `https://hub.docker.com/r/allansimon/allan-docker-dev-python` and launch the command in it (with user `vagrant` )

Comment: Are You Getting error in terminal:- Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-3LYGHv/pyls/

Comment: @DeependraSingh yes, i edited the output , i missed these two lines while copy pasting

Answer (score 1):

I encountered similar issue when jython executing ez_setup.py. It turns out I just had to replace http with https in one of the urls in the script.

Answer (score 1):

In case this might help anyone else...I ran into this issue recently and resolved it by simply updating the pip installer to the latest version:

```
pip install -U pip
```

Comment: This did not fix issue in my setup (ubuntu 22)

Answer (score 0):

I was also attempting to upgrade `pyls` instead of `python-language-server` and I hit the same error. Doing this instead worked for me:

```
pip install --upgrade python-language-server
```

Source: https://github.com/palantir/python-language-server/issues/395

Answer (score -1):

I tried it worked for me:

```
pip install --upgrade pyls -i https://pypi.python.org/simple
```

Comment: doing this command gives me: Cannot unpack file /tmp/pip-z9patb-unpack/simple (downloaded from /tmp/pip-bTRFoA-build, content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8); cannot detect archive format  as if it was trying to install the "simple" package

Comment: There is a '-i' missing before https://pypi.python.org/simple. The full command should be `pip install --upgrade pyls -i https://pypi.python.org/simple`